# Tulip based Qt application only shows black screen. How do I get it to display properly?

Tags: c++, opengl

After going through [all of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220566/qt-tulip-recursive-repaint-detected-in-main-how-to-identify-and-repair-error), I ran into a completely separate problem.

The example standalone graph_display application now compiles and runs without crashing. Most of the functionality seems to look correct, however there is an issue.

Instead of showing the graph represented by the tlp file, I get a black screen.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when you add nodes to a tulip graph, it places them all (dimensionally) in the same space.

Applying a layout will fix the issue of the graph only displaying a black box.

This can be done with a snippet of code like this:

```
Graph *g = tlp::loadGraph(argv[1]);
g->applyPropertyAlgorithm("Circular"
                        g->getProperty<LayoutProperty>("viewLayout"), 
                        message);
```

Comment: Congrats to have worked out the problem. I had tulip built and working without pain (using Ubuntu and Qt 4.8), but I must say it's a fairly complex SW. I was surprised to find no problem while building...

Comment: Yeah, so Tulip itself builds very well. The developers did an excellent job with using CMake. It builds on all platforms for me well.

Comment: But when it comes to building and using the example display_graph, that's another story. The dev's admitted the demos are out of repair lately, and so I had to venture through getting segfaults and getting help from them. Eventually I got it to work, but found that a layout is also appropriate, which isn't included in the example.